# What are some ways to use different background colors in CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Let's say I have 5 webpages and on each webpage I want the background color to be different.  I am using only 1 css file.  Each webpage will be accessed like this: domain.com/page1

Do I simply using 5 different CSS files and just change the background-color in the body or is there a more simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use the same CSS file but give a different class to the body of each webpage?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a single CSS file? Do you really want to put rules for multiple sites in one single file? If you continue down this path, you will have to.

Comment: @jon I am a new person trying stuff out so not really sure of the differences but I thought that most folks would just use a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add different `class` to your `<body>` on each site, and then use that class to get proper background color.

Of course, you don't have to multiply code, that is common to all sites.

Comment: Better to the html tag than the body tag

Comment: Thanks @marcinjuraszek.  I am a newbie and I feel ashamed.  I should've thought of this!!

Comment: @GuidoJansen In HTML4 `class` cannot be added to `<html>` tag

Answer (score 1):

For example:

On "page1":

```
<body id="page1">
```

On "page2":

```
<body id="page2">
```

Your CSS:

```
body#page1 {
    background: red;
}

body#page2 {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well if all pages use the same css file the same background will be used to all...

one easy way to do it is to overrule existing background-color in body. so if you have like a css file containing:

```
body
{
   background-color: aqua;
}
```

then below that (after the css file is implemented) and on the page you need to have a new color you can just overrule it with following:

```
<style type="test/css">
body
{
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a simple inline style to the body tag of each page such as this?

Page 01

```
    <body style="background-color:#111;">
```

Page 02

```
    <body style="background-color:#222;">
```

Page 03

```
    <body style="background-color:#333;">
```

Bare in mind that in regards to design, such proposed variation in colour scheme is often a bad idea. There might be some function behind your idea which would make sense but otherwise I would recommend minimalism coupled with consistency throughout the design process.